# free command: Which column is most relevant?

Tags: linux, memory, debian

I am running a program on a Debian 9 cloud server with 16G of RAM. I am concerned the program may be stressing memory, so I have it run the 'free -h' command as it cycles through a loop. I got the following output toward the end of the program, when memory consumption is maximal:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        6.4G        155M         10M        9.1G        9.0G
Swap:          511M         20K        511M
```

If you look at the 'free' column it looks like there is only 155M free, but if you look at the 'available' column it looks like 9G is available. So, depending on the column, it looks like I have very little memory available, or lots of memory. Which column should I believe?

I've consulted 'man free' but I find it inscrutable.

Comment: With 9GB for buffering/caching there's no stress on the memory. :)

Comment: @tink Unless his application requires that much buffering/caching and is thrashing.

Comment: Well - we can't see that from this **"memory snapshot"** alone

Comment: @DavidSchwartz How would I check for thrashing?

Comment: @tink Right. In fact, you *can't* tell if there's sufficient memory to operate efficiently just from the output of `free`. You have to look at, for example, `vmstat` to tell that. You can have lots of memory used as buffers or cache and you can still be thrashing memory badly if you have applications whose working set doesn't fit in memory. (Consider an application that simply requires more buffers than you have not to thrash.)

Comment: @Argent You look at a tool like `vmstat`. You'll almost never have lots of free memory, so the right question is usually whether or not enough memory is being used for buffering and caching to allow the system to operate without excessive paging/thrashing. You can't tell that from `free`. The unfortunate fact is that there really is no easy way to answer the question, "do I have enough memory for my workload". If you have lots of free memory, then yes. If you have no thrashing or minimal paging, then (usually) yes. Otherwise, it can be *very* hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory that is free is completely unused at this point. This number will generally and ideally be very low, since the OS tries to use as much of this memory as possible for buffering and caching.

The memory that is *freely* available to your application is, in fact, mentioned in the buffering/cached column. 
If your program ran out of memory, it would try to free memory by using swap to outsource data to HDD and free up memory for usage. Considering there's only 20K of swap space used is another indicator that your program is *not* running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends in what context you are talking about memory .

The memory which is free if you see is 155 M .

> However server has set memory for buffer/cache 9.1 GB out of which 9.0 GB is
>   available, which can be used for apps so its unused/free
>
> If we are concerned about system performance only , this  will not degrade system performance until lot of swapping occurs .
>
> But for new apps installation which required more than 155 MB you will get memory error as we have
>   only 155 MB free .